# Solving Implicit function in MATLAB without for loop

Tags: matlab, function, math

I am experiencing a problem and you guys might be of help to me.

In Matlab, I am trying to solve an implicit function, see the following:

```
Cp = Cpi / (  sqrt(1 - M^2) + (M^2 / (sqrt(1-M^2))) * Cpi/2 )
```

Here, I know the values of both M and Cp and want to know the value of Cpi. Also, due to computational time considerations, I would like to avoid using loops in the approach.

Finally, I know that this is not hard to solve, for example one can use the ''golden bi-section'' method to find an answer, however I do not know how to code this in MATLAB. Does anyone know, or has a piece of code which is able to solve for Cpi?

Thank you guys! much appreciated for your help

Comment: Why don't you just rewrite the function to the form Cpi = ... I just did this on a piece of paper in 5 seconds, just write that code down in matlab.

Comment: Its implicit so you cant do that

Comment: It's only implicit under certain conditions. Try `syms Cp Cpi M;` `solve(Cp==Cpi/(sqrt(1-M^2)+M^2/sqrt(1-M^2)*Cpi/2),Cpi)` to get an analytic solution that agrees with the example in @StewieGriffin's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite easily done using [`fzero`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html). If you move the `Cp` part over to the RHS, and try to find the root using `fzero`, with `Cpi` as the variable, you can solve it like this:

```
M = 0.4; Cp = 3;
f = @(Cpi) Cp - (Cpi / (  sqrt(1 - M^2) + (M^2 / (sqrt(1-M^2))) * Cpi/2 ));

fzero(f,0)
ans =
    3.7250
```

Of course, you don't need to assign it to an anonymous function first, but in my opinion, it makes it easier to read.